# JFX image not showing in gridpane

Tags: java, javafx

Here's my code. When compiled only the buttons and labels are displayed in the gridpane but the image wont. I put the image in a resource file thinking this may solve the issue but still it won't show.

public class Main extends Application {

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    //image controls
    Image image = new Image("file:resource/HotAirBalloon.jpg");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

    //Label controls

    Label label1 = new Label ("Label 1");
    Label label2 = new Label ("Label 2");
    Label label3 = new Label ("Label 3");

    //button controls

    Button button1 = new Button("Button1");
    Button button2 = new Button("Button2");
    Button button3 = new Button("Button3");

    VBox vbox = new VBox(10 ,imageView);

    GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

    gridpane.add(button1, 0,0);
    gridpane.add(label1,0,1);

    gridpane.add(button2, 0,2);
    gridpane.add(label2, 0, 3);

    gridpane.add(button3, 0,4);
    gridpane.add(label3, 0,5);
    gridpane.add(vbox, 1,0);



    gridpane.setHgap(10);
    gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(20));





    Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane);


    primaryStage.setScene(scene);

    primaryStage.show();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Comment: part of the code is missing the rest is Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

Comment: `file:resource/HotAirBalloon.jpg` refers to a *relative filename* —meaning, it depends on the current directory of the process.  Make sure HotAirBalloon.jpg is in the same place as your compiled classes, and use `new Image(Main.class.getResource("HotAirBalloon.jpg").toString())`, which will always look for the image in the same place as the class.

Answer (score 0):

i have copied your code as it is and it worked for me, saved the image directly in my src and removed the "file:" part of the path like this:

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends javafx.application.Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //image controls
        Image image = new Image("2.png");
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        //Label controls

        Label label1 = new Label ("Label 1");
        Label label2 = new Label ("Label 2");
        Label label3 = new Label ("Label 3");

        //button controls

        Button button1 = new Button("Button1");
        Button button2 = new Button("Button2");
        Button button3 = new Button("Button3");

        VBox vbox = new VBox(10 ,imageView);

        GridPane gridpane = new GridPane();

        gridpane.add(button1, 0,0);
        gridpane.add(label1,0,1);

        gridpane.add(button2, 0,2);
        gridpane.add(label2, 0, 3);

        gridpane.add(button3, 0,4);
        gridpane.add(label3, 0,5);
        gridpane.add(vbox, 1,0);



        gridpane.setHgap(10);
        gridpane.setPadding(new Insets(20));





        Scene scene = new Scene(gridpane);


        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

[image: screenshot !!]